# events.js:85 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

After an upgrade I can't start a new Ember application on an OS X system any more:

```
$ ember s
version: 1.13.8
Livereload server on http://localhost:49156
Serving on http://localhost:4200/
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
Error: shutdown ENOTCONN
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Socket.onSocketFinish (net.js:240:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:104:17)
    at finishMaybe (_stream_writable.js:484:14)
    at endWritable (_stream_writable.js:493:3)
    at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:459:5)
    at Socket.end (net.js:415:31)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/xyz/Sandbox/tests/tt2/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/sane/node_modules/fb-watchman/index.js:163:17)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
$
```

The software versions:

```
$ ember -v
version: 1.13.8
node: 0.12.7
npm: 2.13.4
os: darwin x64
$
```

What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is watchman's bug. I solve this by `brew uninstall watchman --force watchman`. More details here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2348 .